# How can I add parameters to a workflow in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I'd like to create a custom workflow for SharePoint 2007 (NOT 2010) in Visual Studio.  My need is to have a custom parameter when this workflow is attached to the list.  These would be parameters that I can reference in the Workflow, like a SharePoint ID, email, or other kind of string.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. They are called [Workflow Association (setting default values for workflow) and Initiation (setting/modifying values when starting workflow for each item) Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms481192%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> Association and initiation forms are displayed for users to complete
>   before any workflow actually starts. You can use these forms to enable
>   users to set parameters and other information for the workflow in
>   advance.

You can read [Accessing Data from Workflow Association and Initiation Forms in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160835%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on MSDN

Somwhere on the way in the article you can encounter the following sentance:

> The code shown below is based on the Feedback Collection workflow
>   sample that is provided with the Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SDK

To have these examples at hand, i would suggest you download and install (so you can see how it's done by yourself):

- [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0: Software Development Kit (SDK)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15942)
- [SharePoint Server 2007 SDK: Software Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=79) (if you use
  MOSS)

Comment: This is great info, I had a hard time finding this on the internet for some reason. Thanks!!